# Virtualbox 6 doesn't run with Hyper-V enabled on Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

As explained in the Virtualbox documentation, starting from version 6, Virtualbox supports running VMs un Windows with Hyper-V enabled. It should use Hyper-v in automatic way to run the VMs.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/hyperv-support.html

The issue is it appears to not be true. I'm running a Virtual Box 6 VM, and I get the typical error "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).".

Why?

Comment: have you enabled [nested virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)?

Comment: Nested virtualization is for run hyper-v in a nested hyper-v vm. In this case I'm running Virtual Box in the Host system.

Comment: no, with a hypervisor like Hyper-V the hypervisor is the host, and your Windows is already running in a VM

Comment: Yes, but the host windows VM, has no name, so it's impossible run the command you linked to enable nested virtualization, and it's strange there is no mention about this step in the virtualbox docs.

Comment: Nested virtualization is for Hyper-V as the hypervisor, those commands aren't for VirtualBox.  There are known issues with what you're trying to do and tickets for it: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18387.

Answer (score 19):

> This is an experimental feature.

So this feature could be unstable and doesn't even work.

According to [socratis' thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853&sid=f20b0f7f51e462005f9b3be80a567617&start=120#p453078)

running

```
VBoxManage setextradata "<VM Name>" "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0
```

or

```
VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0
```

can enable hyper-V support.

VBoxManage.exe is in the VirtualBox's install directory.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't appears to work on my PC... I get the same error...

Comment: @Eghes I've seen this before. In my case, I updated my Windows system to the latest insider version and then it works. I don't know whether my Windows system was broken or there was some bugs in it.

Comment: So before you updated to the insider version, didn't it work?

Comment: @Eghes , no, it didn't.

Comment: Also may be needed to enable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" in  OptionalFeatures.exe

Comment: # windows powershell

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform

Comment: Wow, after setting this value (global) on Windows 10 18363.535 running on Intel Core i7-8550U with Hyper-V enabled, all my virtual machines are running flawlessly in VirtualBox 6.1! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Broomerr Unfortunatelly neither this solution works...

Comment: The 1st command worked with Ubuntu distributions using VBox 6.1.2, W10 1909, Hyper-V on, and Docker installed and running with Kubernetes... https://imgur.com/a/1DoMwgG

Answer (score 0):

I think nested virtualization needed for running Windows VMs with Hyper-V is currently only supported for AMD CPUs with AMD-V.  Intel VT-X is not yet supported.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/nested-virt.html

Comment: That's not what the OP is trying to do, there's no nested VMs here.  He's trying to run VirtualBox with Hyper-V enabled.  It's a type 2 hypervisor running in a type 1 hypervisor issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was running my Win 7 32 bits without problems until I enabled Hyper-V. Then I got the BSOD with "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL" error. What I have done was reducing the number of CPU cores assigned to the VM from 4 to 3. Now it´s running OK.