# concurrently running virtualbox, docker and WSL 2.0

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, docker, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Quoting https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/ ,

> Docker Desktop for Windows uses Microsoft Hyper-V for virtualization, and Hyper-V is not compatible with Oracle VirtualBox. Therefore, you cannot run the two solutions simultaneously.

My question is...  if both Docker and VirtualBox use Hyper-V what about WSL 2.0? Does that use Hyper-V and does using WSL 2.0 mean that I *can't* use VirtualBox?

I'm also going to guess that Docker and WSL 2.0 wouldn't be an issue if I use [Docker Desktop WSL 2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/) as opposed to the regular [Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)?

Comment: You misunderstood: VirtualBox does not use Hyper-V. WSL 2 does. WSL 1 doesn't and so is compatible with VirtualBox.

Comment: The in depth cause is somewhat similar with "How to run Hyper-V and VirtualBox simultaneously". See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1489744/726810), it works but slow as hell :(